# How to handle Referential Integrity for Inserts in Access

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007

I'm working on an Access project that I took over from a co-worker. There are three tables that exist: `rules`, `overview` and `relationship`. The `relationship` table has two fields, each is a foreign key that links to a primary key in the other two tables. I have a datasheet view of the `rules` table in a form, where I can delete records with no problems. However, when I try to insert a record into the `rules` table, the record will be inserted into the `rules` table, but there is no matching record inserted into the `relationship` table. I have "Enforce Referential Integrity" checked, as well as "Cascade Update Related Fields" and "Cascade Delete Related Records". I made a naive assumption that this would handle inserts, but clearly I was wrong. So I'm now wondering about the best way to handle this - do I write some VBA for the `After Insert` event of the form that inserts a record into the `relationship` table accordingly?

Comment: If your PKs are Autonumber fields, there is no purpose served in setting CASCADE UPDATE on, as Autonumber fields can't be updated.

Answer (score 3):

The usual way is to either have a form to insert records into rules that is based on a query that includes the relationship table and, say, a combo that allows the user to select the relevant overview, or a form / subform set-up with suitable master / child fields. In the NorthWind sample database, the Order Detail table is an example of your Relationship table, it uses the loathed look-up-in-table anti-feature, but you may get some ideas for further research.

**A Much More Detailed Description of Option 1**

**Tables**

*Overview*
ID
Overview

*Rules*
ID
Rule

*Relationship*
RulesID     ) PK formed by two FKs
OverviewID  )

**Relation**

[image: Relations]

**Data**

[image: Data]

**Suggestion 1 Query Design**

Note that both fields from Relationship are included in the query. It is not necessary to show ID from rules, because it is an autonumber field, but it is included here for simplicity.

If a row is deleted, records from both tables will be deleted.

[image: Query Design]

You cannot violate referential integrity. You will need to have all overviews created before this will work, or provide a different method of adding Overviews.

[image: Violate Integrity]

If you update `RulesID` and `OverviewID`, a record will be added to the Relationship table, but not to Rules.

[image: New Relationship record]

If you update `OverviewID` and `Rule`, records will be added to both Relationship and Rules.

[image: New Rule and Relationship records]

If you create a continuous form, you have all the above in a much more user-friendly way with more control. You can use a combobox to allow the user to select the more friendly description of overview, rather than the ID and you can take advantage of the NotInList event to add new Overviews.

[image: continuous Form]

Note that so far this has not needed a single line of code. That is the power of Access.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Remou. I am trying to leverage the use of the datasheet view, as it seems all of the operations (insert/update/delete) can be done through it. I have a setup that sounds identical to what you mentioned in your first paragraph, where the records displayed in the datasheet view are based on the selected overview type in the combo box. So do you think `After Insert` would be a good place insert a new row into the `relationship` table when inserts occur in the subform/datasheet?

Comment: I've got it working using `After Insert`. I'd provide a pastebin link for anyone else who has this issue, but it's blocked at work.

Comment: @Mitch There is no need to write any code to do what you wish to do. please see above.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed edit. A few questions: 1) You've made your foreign keys in the `relationship` table primary keys - is that necessary if they're already set to "Indexed (Duplicates OK)"? 2) Bar the primary key markers in the `relationship` table, the relationships of my tables are identical to the ones you posted. You said that if I update OverviewID and Rule, records will be added to both Relationship and Rules, but that's not really what I want - the user shouldn't have to do that. I want to be able to add a record to `rules` and have it propagate through to `relationship`.

Comment: 3) As for the continuous form thing, I'm pretty sure I have that already. I've got a datasheet view of the `rules` table, which displays only the rules that have a matching overview in the relationships table that is the same as what the user has chosen from the overview combo box (which doesn't display IDs).

Comment: @Mitch Duplicates of the two foreign keys should not be possible in a junction table, which is what the relationships table is. How do you see the OverViewID being added to Relationship table if the user is not selecting the ID?

Comment: I think we're talking about slightly different things.. I was clarifying that the user is selecting the overview ID from the combo box - but their list of options is the description of each overview, not the ID. I'd like them to be able to insert a new row in the `rules` datasheet view, after they've selected an overview from the combo box (which filters the displayed rules by overview), which will then be inserted into `rules` and a corresponding record inserted into `relationship`.

Comment: In regards to the keys in the `relationship` table, I apologise for not mentioning that the rulesID is set to "Indexed (No Duplicates)", as there can be multiple rules per overview.

Comment: I think the best bet would be to send you a sample database. I am fairly sure that the example I have set up is what you want. If the key on relationships is a combination of RulesID and OverviewID, then you can have a lot of the same rules and a lot of the same overiews, just not the same overview with the same rule.

Comment: Sounds good. I'd prefer not to give out my email here - is there some other way I can get it to you? I'm not logged in to my actual account because I log in through my Google account.. which is blocked at work.

Comment: Use chat see line: `Please avoid extended discussions in comments. Would you like to automatically move this discussion to chat?`

Comment: I tried that before and an error occurred, then I clicked the chat link manually and it appears that that is also blocked... everything at this place is blocked haha.

Comment: @Mitch Rats :) Go to lessthandot.com, it is a tech site, so it may not be blocked. It has private messaging for me, or just email the site and someone will tell me.

Comment: Wow, my work is so absolutely terrible that they block the page that I need to go to to activate my account with less than dot. Why am I here again?

Answer (score 0):

If the key in question is an autonumber (`IDENTITY`) and one table references the other (via a foreign key) then you can create a `VIEW` joining two tables, insert into the view, and the autonumber value gets automatically copied to the referencing table. Here's a quick demo:

```
Sub RulesOverview()
  On Error Resume Next
  Kill Environ$("temp") & "\DropMe.mdb"
  On Error GoTo 0

  Dim cat
  Set cat = CreateObject("ADOX.Catalog")

  With cat
    .Create _
    "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
    "Data Source=" & _
    Environ$("temp") & "\DropMe.mdb"

    With .ActiveConnection

      Dim Sql As String

      Sql = _
      "CREATE TABLE Rules ( " & _
      " ID INTEGER IDENTITY NOT NULL UNIQUE,  " & _
      " Rule VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL UNIQUE " & _
      ")"

      .Execute Sql

      Sql = _
      "CREATE TABLE Overview ( " & _
      " OverviewID INTEGER IDENTITY NOT NULL UNIQUE, " & _
      " Overview VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL UNIQUE " & _
      ")"

      .Execute Sql

      Sql = _
      "CREATE TABLE Relationship ( " & _
      " RuleID INTEGER NOT NULL " & _
      "    REFERENCES Rules (ID) " & _
      "    ON DELETE CASCADE, " & _
      " OverviewID INTEGER " & _
      "    REFERENCES Overview (OverviewID) " & _
      "    ON DELETE SET NULL, " & _
      " Name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL, " & _
      " UNIQUE (RuleID, OverviewID) " & _
      ")"

      .Execute Sql

      Sql = _
      "CREATE VIEW RulesRelationship AS " & _
      "SELECT Rules.ID, " & _
      "       Rules.Rule, " & _
      "       Relationship.RuleID, " & _
      "       Relationship.Name " & _
      "  FROM Rules INNER JOIN Relationship " & _
      "          ON Rules.ID = Relationship.RuleID;"

      .Execute Sql

      Sql = _
      "INSERT INTO RulesRelationship (Rule, Name) " & _
      "   VALUES ('Don''t run with scissors', " & _
      "           'Initial scissors');"

      .Execute Sql

      Sql = _
      "SELECT * FROM RulesRelationship;"

      Dim rs
      Set rs = .Execute(Sql)
      MsgBox rs.GetString

    End With
    Set .ActiveConnection = Nothing
  End With
End Sub
```

Comment: It's not immediately obvious to me if this will work with the table structure that Remou posted (as that is a simplified depiction of mine).

Comment: @Mitch: Your spec says that when you insert a record into the `rules` table you want a matching row to be automatically inserted into the relationship `table`. This can be achieved using the model I posted (I changed the table names, of course). However, using @Remou's model (quote), "You will need to have all overviews created before this will work, or provide a different method of adding Overviews." I chose to answer your question rather than build on @Remou's answer ;)

Comment: @Mitch: I've updated my code sample to use the meta data from @Remou's answer, added an attribute `Relationship.Name` for demo purposes.