# Insert data in two tables in vb and Ms-Access

Tags: ms-access, vb6

I am working on project of VB (6) and MS - Access. There are two tables,
1) User table
2) User roles

User_id is the PK of **USER** and FK in **ROLES** and has a relation b/w two tables. Is there anyway to insert data in two tables at one time. Please refer me any link or tutorial.

Thankx buddies

Comment: maybe accept some answers on your previous questions first?

Comment: Why do you want to insert the same data twice? Sounds like you have a DB design problem.

Answer (score 1):

Create a query in the Access query design window joining the two tables on User_id. Make sure you add all relevant fields to the grid. Test it, you should find that you can add records to both tables, but the order of entry may be important. This may help: [How to handle Referential Integrity for Inserts in Access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7397949/how-to-handle-referential-integrity-for-inserts-in-access/7398332#7398332)