# how to add rows to more than one table at same time?

Tags: ms-access

I have four tables each with its own form, all these table share same column which is the unique id. How do i update other tables when i add new row in one form at same time, that is how do i get a row in other tables with unique id and other columns being empty?

Is there a way to specify more than one control source to the unique id field?

I tried the approach in making one to one relationships between unique id in one table to other tables unique ids But this did not work.

Comment: You should post some table schemas. look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7397949/how-to-handle-referential-integrity-for-inserts-in-access/7398332#7398332 and see if it describes what you want to do. Finally, post the version of Access that you will be using.

Comment: I am using MS Access 2007. The three tables are reference, field data, lab data. Each table has autoincrement field and record number (this should be same for each row in each of the tables). Also there are three forms respectively. So i need to add record number to other two tables when user adds a new record to reference table.

Comment: Do you expect to add a record to each table? If so, you may wish to consider reference as your main form with subforms for field and lab tables. If you want a proper answer, you must post schemas or sample data. You can edit your question to add the information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could execute INSERT statements from the form's before or after insert events.  If your form has a text box named txtID bound to the ID field in the form's record source:

```
Private Sub Form_AfterInsert()
Dim db As DAO.Database
Set db = CurrentDb
db.Execute "INSERT INTO Table2 (ID) VALUES (" & Me.txtID & ");", dbFailOnError
db.Execute "INSERT INTO Table3 (ID) VALUES (" & Me.txtID & ");", dbFailOnError
db.Execute "INSERT INTO Table4 (ID) VALUES (" & Me.txtID & ");", dbFailOnError
Set db = Nothing
End Sub
```

That approach assumes all the fields in those tables other than the ID fields will accept Null values (in table design view, the Required property is No).

But it might be better to do this from the before insert event, and cancel the INSERT for the current form if any of the other inserts fail.  And in that case you may also want to roll back any of those other inserts which succeeded --- this could easily get more complicated.

**Edit**: I gave you a very rough outline.  Now that you're getting the too few parameters message, suggest you revise it along these lines so you can view the exact INSERT statements you're asking the db engine to execute.

```
Private Sub Form_AfterInsert()
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim strSql As String
Set db = CurrentDb
strSql = "INSERT INTO Table2 (ID) VALUES (" & Me.txtID & ");"
Debug.Print strSql
db.Execute strSql, dbFailOnError
strSql = "INSERT INTO Table3 (ID) VALUES (" & Me.txtID & ");"
Debug.Print strSql
db.Execute strSql, dbFailOnError
strSql = "INSERT INTO Table4 (ID) VALUES (" & Me.txtID & ");"
Debug.Print strSql
db.Execute strSql, dbFailOnError
Set db = Nothing
End Sub
```

You can view the output from those Debug.Print statements in the Immediate window.  (You can get to the Immediate window with Ctrl+g)  You can also test any of those statements by copying it from the Immediate window and then pasting it into SQL View of a new query.

**Edit2**: If Record_Num is text (such as R98609) rather than numeric data type, add quotes around the values when you build the INSERT statements.

```
strSql = "INSERT INTO Table2 (ID) VALUES ('" & Me.txtID & "');"
```

Comment: I am getting this error: Run-time error 3061 Too few parameters for this code I tried:Private Sub Form_AfterInsert()

    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Set db = CurrentDb
    db.Execute "INSERT INTO Lab_Data (Record_Num) VALUES (" & Form_Reference.recordNum & ");", dbFailOnError
    db.Execute "INSERT INTO Field_Data (Record_Num) VALUES (" & Form_Reference.recordNum & ");", dbFailOnError     Set db = Nothing

End Sub

Comment: ok i fixed that problem but i am getting error 424 object required

Comment: this line db.Execute "INSERT INTO Lab_Data (Record_Num) VALUES (" & Form_Reference.recordNum & ");"

Comment: Hmmmm.  Is the db object variable still valid? --- not been destroyed?  What does Debug.Print of the INSERT statement look like?  Does it work when you paste it into SQL View of a new query?

Comment: i tried this: Private Sub Form_AfterInsert()
    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim strSql As String
    Set db = CurrentDb
    strSql = "INSERT INTO Lab_Data (Record_Num) VALUES (" & Me.recordNum & ");"
    Debug.Print strSql
    db.Execute strSql, dbFailOnError
    strSql = "INSERT INTO Field_data (Record_Num) VALUES (" & Me.recordNum & ");"
    Debug.Print strSql
    db.Execute strSql, dbFailOnError
 
    Set db = Nothing
End Sub

Comment: Error is 3061 Too few parameters

Comment: Did you examine the Debug.Print output for strSql?  My guess is that strSql doesn't contain the valid INSERT statement you need.  If you can't see how to fix it after pasting it into SQL View of a new query and experimenting with it there ... then paste it in here so we can see it.

Comment: INSERT INTO Lab_Data(Record_Num) VALUES (R98609); but stops at db.Execute strSql, dbFailOnError.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps a better question is why you have four tables with the same primary key, have you considered putting all the data in the one table